# Entity framework Group by query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Let's say I have a table with the following data:

```
Id | title | image | page
-------------------------
 1   test    a.jpg    1
 2   test    b.jpg    2
 3   test 1  c.jpg    1
 4   test 1  d.jpg    2
```

How would I go about grouping the data by title and retrieving the first results. Like so:

```
Id | title | image | page
-------------------------
 1   test    a.jpg    1
 3   test 1  c.jpg    1
```

What I have tried so far but without luck is:

```
var result = _db.Records.Select(r => new Records
        {
            Id = r.Id,
            title = r.title,
            image = r.image,
            page = r.page
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
        .GroupBy(x => x.title)
        .Select(x => x.First()).AsQueryable();
```

Am I going about this the right way? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you grouping by Id *and* title? Shouldn't it be just `GroupBy(x => x.title)`?

Comment: Yup, that was just some wrong pasted code, I'll update it.

Comment: You should remove the .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)

Comment: I do not see any obvious problem with this query. It should work, although there is no need for first `Select`, and ordering before grouping does not make a lot of sense since it will be lost anyway. What is not working for you here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'retrieving the first results'? The first group?

Comment: Sorry I just meant as shown below that statement. The first records that match the group by title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why order by and why return AsQueryable? This is what I have done. If you must return a queryable, appending AsQueryable() will still work.

```
Records.GroupBy (r => r.Title)
.Select (r =>r.First ())
```

Comment: So many different ways it seems. Thanks this is producing my desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The first Select doesn't seem to do anything. You already have Records and you're selecting Records.
The second Select is also not needed. Instead of calling `x => x.First()` why not call `First()` ? Or am I missing something?

```
var result = _db.Records
    //.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .GroupBy(x => x.title)
    .First();
```

Edit: the OrderBy is doing work that is negated (somewhat) by the GroupBy

Edit 2: The above will only get the first group. So the x => x.First() was correct:

```
var result = _db.Records
    .GroupBy(x => x.title)
    .Select(group => group.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results
    = _db.Records.GroupBy(
        i => i.title,
        (key, group) => group.First()
    )
```

Hope this helps